# TeamCity dynamic parameters

Tags: teamcity

I am new to TeamCity.

I need to create a configuration parameters for build (android).
Configuration parameters should consists from git branch (branch to build), build type and where to push the build (if i choose to push at all).

[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udi9V.png)

1. How to automatically populate "Build Branch" field with git branches from my repo?
2. Depending on what is selected in "Build Type" [Release|Debug] how to automatically change what is available for selection in "Make Public" field.

Example:
If "Build Type" is Debug then A and B should be available to select in "Make Public" field.
If "Build Type" is Release then C and D should be available to select in "Make Public" field.

TeamCity version: "TeamCity Professional 2018.1.1 (build 58406)".

Comment: 1) why you pass the branch instead of use VCS root?

Comment: Idea is to send specific feature to testers, we have feature branches and for testers to do testing they need a build. Feature => Feature branch => Feature build => Testers => Issues

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the **VCS Roots**.

1. Go to
2. Create VCS Root
3. Attach this VCS to your build

   - General Settings
   - Version Control Settings
   - Attach VCS root

   [image]

Now your project able to build on the different branch

Create the Parameter Build_Type

Click to **Spec: Edit**

The construction

```
Debug => A,B
Release => C,D
```

means if I choose Debug, the real value of the parameter `%Build_Type%` is **A,B**

TC hasn't an opportunity to create a depends parameters what you want. But you can use the real value of Build_Type.

*The second way is:*

User selects the Build_Type and Make_Public. 
Run the custom script to determine the needed value and pass it to project.

*One more way:*

Create a template of builds 
Create 2 projects where 1th has one parameter, the second project has another

[image]